# How to add ViewModel localization to Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

We all know the lack of ViewModel localization in Blazor

Today i tried many ways, and i came up with a good method to be followed to apply localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can create an abstract base ViewModel for all properties for example “ProductViewModelBase“
- Then makes all of your ViewModelBase Properties as virtual

> ```
>  public abstract class ProductViewModelBase
>  {
>                public virtual string ProductCode { get; set; }
>                public virtual string ProductType { get; set; }
>                public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
>  }
> ```

- Then for your ViewModel languages override any property and add your specific language message and validation rules.

> ```
>   public class ProductViewModelAR : ProductViewModelBase
>     {
>             [Required(ErrorMessage = "خطأ")]
>             public override string ProductCode { get; set; }
>     }
>
>
>
>
>
>  public class ProductViewModelEN : ProductViewModelBase
>     {
>             [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")] 
>             public override string ProductCode { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

- In your Blazor component, check which ViewModel to load

> ```
> ProductViewModelBase ViewModel;
>
> protected override void OnInitialized()
> {
>     if (CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name == "ar-EG")
>     {
>         ViewModel = new ProductViewModelAR();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         ViewModel = new ProductViewModelEN();
>     }
> }
> ```

**And Now you can use this ViewModel in your EditForm**

> ```
> <EditForm Model="ViewModel" OnValidSubmit="ValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="InValidSubmit">
>     <DataAnnotationsValidator />
>     <ValidationSummary />
>
> </EditForm>
> ```

*And in Run-time the app will decide which ViewModel version to load based on the selected language*

Comment: You also might find [Chris Sainty's article](https://chrissainty.com/simple-localisation-in-blazor/) useful since client-side Blazor can't read the culture information

Comment: I'd suggest this approach will work for two or three locales but won't scale very well - you might find that [Fluent Validation](https://fluentvalidation.net/localization) would represent a better approach since it de-couples the Model from the Validation logic

Answer (score 2):

`DataAnnotations` validation is probably not the best way to achieve this as the validation logic is tied to the class, and as you saw in your own answer, it means a lot of duplication.

[FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/localization) provides an answer since it actually has built-in localization support (it also has built-in messages in many languages for default validations!).

I created a [demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/conficient/BlazorValidationLocalization) to show how it works.

As you can see this solution is a lot simpler.

[image: English] [image: Arabic]

Comment: I browsed through your code. Can you explain how this works for custom error messages with localization?

Comment: You should read https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/localization.html - I think `.WithLocalizedMessage` is probably what you need.

Comment: you said the demo project on GitHub shows how it works. But I couldn't see it there. Yes, I was able to get the FluentValidator working based on their documentation.