# How to Localize validation message (DataAnnotationsValidator) in blazor server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-localization

I am using blazor 3.1 in latest version of VS 2019.

So far, I am able to localize page labels (title, table fields etc.).

On the `ListEmployee.razor` page, I am able to localize table heading etc. On the `AddEmplyeeValidation.razor` page, I am able to localize form labels but I have a problem localizing the validation messages.

For validation message for the `Employee.cs` file, validation message are defined in the `Resources/Data` folder in files `Data.Employee.resx` and `Data.Employee.ar.resx` but this doesn't seem to work.

```cs
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace BlazorSPA1.Data
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            [MaxLength(50)]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [Required (ErrorMessage ="Name is RRRequired")]
            [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long.")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(20)]
            public string Department { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string Designation { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string Company { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string City { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

How can I load the validation messages from the resource files based on language for my `AddEmployeForm`?

```cs
    @page "/addemployeeValidation"
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
    @inject IEmployeeService EmployeeService
    @inject IStringLocalizer<AddEmployeeValidation> L

    <h2>Create Employee</h2>
    <hr />
    <EditForm Model="@employee" OnValidSubmit="@CreateEmployee">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name" class="control-label">@L["Name"]</label>
                    <input for="Name" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Name" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(()=> employee.Name)" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Department" class="control-label">@L["Department"]</label>
                    <input for="Department" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Department" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Designation" class="control-label">@L["Designation"]</label>
                    <input for="Designation" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Designation" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Company" class="control-label">@L["Company"]</label>
                    <input for="Company" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Company" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="City" class="control-label">@L["City"]</label>
                    <input for="City" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.City" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn" @onclick="@Cancel" value="Cancel" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>

    @code {

        Employee employee = new Employee();

        protected async Task CreateEmployee()
        {
            await EmployeeService.CreateEmployee(employee);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("listemployees");
        }


        void Cancel()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("listemployees");
        }
    }
```

I have read a few articles and tried few thing but nothing seems to be working.

Here is my `Startup.cs` code:

```cs
        services.AddServerSideBlazor(options => options.DetailedErrors = true);
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("ar") };
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en");
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
```

I am using the following example for localization but it doesn't show how to localize error messages:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/localization-in-blazor-server/

Folder structure image for reference:

[image]

Resource file example for English version in same way i have Arabic file also:

[image]

In the screenshot below, you will see field names are being pulled correctly from the Resource file but validation messages are not working and only display in English.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is my solution for localizing data annotation error messages. I create two resource files, one for fields and another one for error messages.

- `DisplayNameResource` for localizing fields
- `ErrorMessageResource` for localizing error messages

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In view model class use `Display` attribute for localizing field name. To specify resource file use `ResourceType` property on `Display` attribute:

```
[Display(Name = "Address", ResourceType = typeof(DisplayNameResource))]
```

And on validation attributes use `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` to specify resource file:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource))]
```

Here is full example:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Address", ResourceType = typeof(DisplayNameResource))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource))]
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLengthError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource))]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone", ResourceType = typeof(DisplayNameResource))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource))]
    [RegularExpression("^09([0-9]{9})$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "PhoneLengthError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource))]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(DisplayNameResource))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource))]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinxMaxLengthError")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ConfirmPassword", ResourceType = typeof(DisplayNameResource))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource))]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinxMaxLengthError")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordConfirmMisMatch", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource))]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Error message for `MaxLengthError` is `{0} cannot be longer than {1} character`, so `{0}` will be replaced with localized filed name and `{1}` will be replaced with the `256` you specified on attribute `[StringLength(256,...`

Comment: I will try this out it seems it should work.. I would appreciate if you could post this on Github as this kind or question will often raised and there are huge number of multilingual options..

Comment: @Learning I'll put complete example on github for sure.

Comment: This will be of great help to lot  of programmer like me as Blazor doesnt have much example in my context...

Comment: Just pointing out you have to change the `Access Modifier` on the Resource file to `Public` from the default of `No code generated` for Resource files for this to work.  Otherwise the `typeof` can't find the object!

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked before:

[How to add ViewModel localization to Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033230/how-to-add-viewmodel-localization-to-blazor)

I suggested that using FluentValidation would be a better approach. Here is a link to my Github repo that demonstrates how it could work:

https://github.com/conficient/BlazorValidationLocalization

Comment: I had this kind of solution in mind but this will two modal files for each and if project is large it will become it difficult to manage, Yes this is a work around and make thing work...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "two modal files". You can still use resx with FluentValidation. see https://fluentvalidation.net/localization

Answer (score 0):

**I did not tried this out!**

In the offical docs of asp.net core there is section how to localize `DataAnnotations`
Maybe you find some [clues there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1).