# Blazor WebAssembly Client DataAnnotations Localization

Tags: localization, client, blazor, data-annotations, webassembly

Asp.net core server side localization is well documented and working for me. But how do you localize DataAnnotations on DTO models on the client side of Blazor webassembly?

On server side I've added the code below and DataAnnotations are localized. Everything is working as expected.

```
...
services
.AddRazorPages()              .AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                        {
                            return factory.Create(typeof(CommonStrings));
                        };

                    });
...
```

But how do I do the same thing on Blazor client side (webassembly)?
For example I have this model which is on client side:

```
public class ApplicationUserDTO
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Field {0} is required")]
        [Display(Name ="First name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }


    }
```

I want to post it to backend via `<EditForm>` component, and before I do that do the validation on client side.
I also want to localize it like i would on aspnet.core server - Error/validation messages and display names...

I tried with LocalizedValidator component:

```
    public class MessageValidatorBase<TValue> : ComponentBase, IDisposable
    {
        private FieldIdentifier _fieldIdentifier;
        private EventHandler<ValidationStateChangedEventArgs> _stateChangedHandler
            => (sender, args) => StateHasChanged();
        [CascadingParameter]
        private EditContext EditContext { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public Expression<Func<TValue>> For { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public string Class { get; set; }
        protected IEnumerable<string> ValidationMessages =>
            EditContext.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier);
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            _fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(For);
            EditContext.OnValidationStateChanged += _stateChangedHandler;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            EditContext.OnValidationStateChanged -= _stateChangedHandler;
        }
    }
```

and then created component:

```
@typeparam TValue
@inherits MessageValidatorBase<TValue>
@inject StringLocalizationService _localizer
@foreach (var message in ValidationMessages)
{
    <div class="@Class">
        @_localizer[message]
        
    </div>
}
```

but the problem is I get already expanded string here. For example if I have error message like this "The field {0} is required" I get "The field First name is required" which will not be localized since I don't have the resource with that key and I don't intend to translate the same error message for every property name...

[EDIT]
I just want to know if there is something trivial I didn't do instead of implementing it completely on my own

Comment: I think there might be a way to use localisation like for ui - with .resx files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Localize validation message (DataAnnotationsValidator) in blazor server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59659489/how-to-localize-validation-message-dataannotationsvalidator-in-blazor-server-s)

Comment: @Quango I didn't want to accept that as an answer since it clearly says "server side" and this is about client side

Comment: @Darftagan that would not make a difference

Comment: @Quango It could be potentially confusing for someone reading this later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### WebAssembly example.

#### Example property

```
[MaxLength(5,  ErrorMessageResourceName = "LengthError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.App))]
public string Prefix { get; set; }
```

Create a folder in your client called Resources.
Add a `.resx' file for each language plus a default (no language).

[image]

Make sure your set the access Modifier to `Public`
[image]

#### Example output in French.

[image]

Comment: I just want to add that if you want to localize DisplayAttribute you must avoid spaces in Name property. I had "First name" and i was getting error "Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type 'Resources.Resource' is not public..." even though it was public and "First name" key exists, as soon as I had "FirstName" instead everything started working...

Comment: @Darftagan this is a result of setting the resource to public, this also instructs the compiler to produce the static class. Property names cannot contain spaces of course. 
To deal with this I use a separate `.resx` files for data annotations.

Comment: I agree. I just mentioned it in case someone has resource with key that has spaces.

Comment: Has anyone tried this with Access Modifier left as 'No code gen', and with spaces in the ResourceName?
If using the IStringLocalizer in regular ASP.net logic (razor pages etc) then it's possible to use the 'default' text as the name, spaces and all.. and if it can't be found it's just returned as-is.  Would be nice if the same happened for Data Annotations.

Comment: @BevanWeiss this is for data annotations. Use keys without spaces.